# Obtaining Integer Enumeration Value for a Font style

Tags: c#, .net, text, fonts, enumeration

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the enumeration values supported for the font styles are

```
Bold text.  1
```

Italic

```
Italic text.    2
```

Regular

```
Normal text.    0
```

Strikeout

```
Text with a line through the middle.    8
```

Underline

```
Underlined text.    4
```

There are many fonts which have additional styles apart from these.How can get the enumeration integer value for a particular font from the Style of that font

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply cast it to an integer:

```
var intRepresentation = (int)myFont.Style;
```

If your goal is to work out what style a font is a better approch would be something like this:

```
var isBold = myFont.Style & FontStyle.Bold; // isBold is 0 if not, 1 if it is
var isItalic = myFont.Style & FontStyle.Italic; // isItalic is 0 if not, 2 if it is
```

See the Enumeration as Bit Flags section of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Comment: Read the section i've edited in, that shows how to determine what flags are set, and how to set them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the support.Are there extra enumeration integer values for fonts offering additional styles.

Comment: No, you can see the different options if you right-click on FontStyles in visual studio then click go to definition, or you can look at MSDN.